# How to include external JS libraries like jQuery, jQuery DataTable, Charts.js with Parcel Bundler?

Tags: javascript, bundler, parcel, parceljs

I'm new to parcel and i need some help here: I have some external JS libraries that I used in my website development. So how do I include all those in my build? Note: I've used all CDN URLS like this

```html
<script defer src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script&gt;
<script defer src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy.

- Install the desired dependency

```
npm i jquery
```

- Use it in your code

```js
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

That's it. Bundling and even minification, Parcel will do automatically.

If you prefer to keep them on CDN, just include them into index.html and keep them there. You might install types with `npm i @types/jquery -D` if you want IntelliSense.

If you don't use something directly in the code, you may create separate file with vendors and import it directly to the HTML:

```js
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';
```

```html
  <script src="./vendors.ts"></script>
```

You may look for real-life example here: https://github.com/Drag13/perfrunner/blob/development/packages/perfrunner-reporters/src/reporters/html/index.html

**Important:** don't mix the approaches, you will do double loading.

Answer (score 2):

With parcel v2 (parcel@next) I load form CDN jquery and this is my setup.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
```

**package.json**

```
"alias": {
  "jquery": {
    "global": "$"
  }
}
...
```

**main.js**

`import $ from 'jquery'; $('id').toggle() // use jquery`

I compile it like

`parcel build main.js`

The end result has my code and jquery has to be loaded *before*.
Note my example is not optimized for async load etc.

ps: I have to say I'm not expert in parcel(starting to learn) but this works for me.